# Prove inequality using taylor

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, taylor-expansion

I need to use Taylor in order to prove this inequality:

$\tan(x)>x+\frac{x^3}{3}$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$

I know that $\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+R_3(x)$, but I don't know how to prove that the error ($R_3(x))$ is positive.

Comment: You are mistaken. For the inequality to hold, the error term must be positive.

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\tan(x)-x-\frac{x^3}3$. Then\begin{align}f'(x)&=1+\tan^2(x)-1-x^2\\&=\tan^2(x)-x^2.\end{align}But, in $\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$, $\tan(x)>x$, and therefore $\tan^2(x)>x^2$. So, $f'(x)>0$ there. So, since $f(0)=0$, $f(x)>0$ there.

Comment: I need to use taylor

Comment: Here you go: https://images.app.goo.gl/eMkQZEryysvDtuNEA (Happy belated April Fools!)